# What is the name of this symbol "♪"?

Tags: terminology, symbols, music

I need the names of the following symbols:

- ♪
- The one that is not coloured in and looks like a "d"
- The circular one, that looks like an "o"
- The one like this ♪, but doesn't have the little thingy sticking out

Answer (score 29):

The ♪ symbol is called a quaver, it represents 1/8th of the total duration represented by a full note

The one that looks similar to ♪, but doesn't have the little thingy sticking out and is not coloured inside is called a minim and is half of a full note

[image]

PS: if I understand it correctly, the "common name" above refers to what they are known as in the US. The traditional names for the notes are the ones in the Classical Note Name and are also more frequently used in music books

Comment: The "Classical Note Name" is usually associated more with British speakers. I've never heard someone call a half note a "Minim" here in the US (although we were taught that's what people call it in Britain)

Answer (score 19):

> EDIT My answer has the most upvotes (as I type this). However I now believe that the answer provided by user13267 is better. I also think that the answer by Drew adds useful information.

In the US, the answer is as given by the user lightbulb.

In the UK we have individual names for them. ♪ is a quaver, ♩ is a crotchet. Then we have minim, semibreve and breve.

Note that I have answered your query about the **names** of symbols. If you have queries about the **meaning** and execution of the symbols you will find the [Music Stack Exchange](https://music.stackexchange.com/) very useful.

Answer (score 14):

The Unicode character you used, `♪`, is named `EIGHTH NOTE`.  (Its Unicode code point is `9834` decimal, `266A` hexadecimal.)

The "d"-like character `♩` is named `QUARTER NOTE`. (Its code point is `9833` decimal, `2669` hexadecimal.)

This, empty-"d" character, , is named `MUSICAL SYMBOL HALF NOTE`. (Its code point is `119134` decimal, `1D15E` hexadecimal.)  But it does not show properly in the font used here.

See [this](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf) for more about Unicode musical note symbols (characters).

Comment: Just out of curiosity (and not really related to the question here at all): is there anywhere where referencing Unicode code points in decimal is the norm/more common than in hexadecimal?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: There is no such norm, nor should there be. In an application it is typically the *number* that counts. How that number is represented (as a numeral) externally is up to the application. Some applications accept multiple numeral representations of the same number, including decimal, octal, and hexadecimal.

Comment: I didn’t mean ‘norm’ in the sense of ‘codified standard’, but in the sense of ‘something commonly done’; I’m aware that it doesn’t matter to the vast majority of applications. I only ask because I’ve never come across anyone who chose to reference Unicode code points in decimal in descriptive text before (much less binary, quinary, octal, tercentimal, etc.), and I was wondering whether doing so was common in some specific area.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Emacs. If you put the cursor before such a character and you hit a particular help key, you get a complete description of that character. The description includes various number representations (numerals) of the code point, its Unicode decomposition if composed, and so on. Similarly, you can input or manipulate a character using any supported representation. This is no different from how, say, RGB or HSV color values are represented - sometimes decimal is used, sometimes hex. In a programming context it typically does not matter, because multiple representations are accepted.

Answer (score 13):

Those symbols are examples of musical notes.

In American English:

♪ is an eighth note. ♩ is a quarter note. The other symbols are "half" and "whole" notes respectively. Their names reflect the notes' durations as a fraction of a measure in 4/4 time.